# Splitting javascript object to normal String with = sign

Tags: javascript

How can I dynamically convert a json object to the following manner
I do have

```
{ eligible: true, qualified:true }
```

but I need to make it like this

```
eligible= true, qualified=true
```

Comment: Is the space before the first `true` in the expected output deliberate/required?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Is the output a string?

Comment: @CertainPerformance am sorry ,space is not deliberate

Comment: Why don't you use REGEX?

Comment: is the expected output a string?

Comment: @void i am trying to achieve this to log in our splunk dashboards, which will accept in this format only

Comment: It's either an object, or a string/text in JSON format. There's no such thing as a "JSON object". You can use `Object.keys(myObj)` to get an array of keys., then use `.map` to create a new array. There's also `.join()`.

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati: yes we can use regex ,but i dont have it handy

Comment: Your JSON is invalid - keys need to be surrounded in `"`s, best to fix that, and then you can turn it into an object with `JSON.parse`

Comment: @ChrisG can you help me this jsfiddle or code

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and the Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: You just got spoonfed twice, why do you need a fiddle on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume the string is a valid JSON object (yours is missing the quotes) you can parse the string as JSON and then use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key value pairs which can then be mapped and joined down to your desired string output.

```js
const jsonStr = '{ "eligible": true, "qualified":true }'
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr)

console.log(Object.entries(jsonObj).map(e => e.join('=')).join(', '))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a two dimensional array of object and then use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to join the array element (key, value) with an `=`.

Finally join the array with a `,` to get the expected output.

```js
var x = { eligible: true, qualified:true };

var newX = Object.entries(x).map(el => el.join("=")).join(", ");

console.log(newX);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get entries of object and change the `key/value` to string using `reduce`

```js
let obj = { eligible: true, qualified:true }


let str = Object.entries(obj).reduce((op,[key,value],index,arr)=>{
  op+= `${key}=${value}${index !== arr.length-1 ? ',' : ''} `
  return op
},'')

console.log(str.trim())
```